# CSV Reading data Stock Prices

Tags: python, database, csv, ram

Hi I would like to get stock prices data in an csv-file. I can read the stock prices but can't see them as a csv file.

I have searched for an soultion but couldn't find it.

```
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
#my api server
ts = TimeSeries(key='YOUR_API_KEY',output_format='csv')
data = ts.get_intraday(symbol='AAPL',interval='1min', outputsize='compact')
print(data)
#(<_csv.reader object at 0x0F461370>, None)
```

How can I save the data now as an csv-file to work with it?

Niklas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `csv` reader object. You can either iterate it or use `list`

**Ex:**

```
print(list(data))
```

or

```
for row in data:
    print(row)
```

To write CSV to file use:

```
import csv

with open("outfile.csv", "w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: If i do that:'from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
import csv
ts = TimeSeries(key='YOUR_API_KEY',output_format='csv')
data = ts.get_intraday(symbol='AAPL',interval='1min', outputsize='compact')
#print(list(data))
for row in data:
    print(row)' The Output is still: '[Running] python -u "d:\Python\Programme\Wirtschaft\v2 Niklas ein weniger Noob\tests\test neue api alpha cvs.py"
<_csv.reader object at 0x0D8EF2F0>
None

[Done] exited with code=0 in 4.135 seconds'

Comment: Looks like you have exhausted the generator. Try `data = list(ts.get_intraday(symbol='AAPL',interval='1min', outputsize='compact'))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python **Pandas**

[Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)

It has many features, like the ones you need, reading from dataframe or exporting to CSV. You can do much more things using the Pandas DataFrame.

[DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)